# What does "lp" stand for in execlp command

Tags: c, unix

I google it, which says it's line printer. I don't think it make any sense...

Comment: You're too young if "line printer" makes no sense to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `l` is for list and the `p` is for path.  Check out all the other [variants](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/execl.3.html), e.g. execl, execlp, execle, execv, execvp.

Comment: In the future please avoid linking to `die.net`. It's serving horribly outdated versions of the man pages that somehow have worked their way to the top of search engine rank by everyone finding and linking them (a feedback effect). If you want Linux man pages, the ones on `kernel.org` are authoritative and up-to-date.

Comment: @R.. Thank you for educating me. I have updated the answer as per your advice.

Answer (score 1):

at the prompt try: "man execlp"

See also: [Linux Man Pages](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the man page for [`execlp(3)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=execl&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE)

The `execl` family of functions executes a file, passing a null-terminated **L**ist of string arguments. `execlp()` searches the users **P**ath, as the shell would.

Answer (score -3):

I would try googling the entire command name:

[Google Results](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pwst=1&biw=1260&bih=755&sa=X&ei=ubrKTbmgOMbJgQee9KmFBg&ved=0CBUQvgUoAA&q=what%20is%20excelp%20command&nfpr=1)

The first result provides a lot of information that might help:

[Linux / Unix Command: execlp](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execlp.htm)